# sweetalert2 is not working fine

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, sweetalert

I'm using rails 5, Now trying to use SweetAlert2 for data confirmation prompt, SweetAlert2 prompt is appearing but not deleting the data and showing warning in console like this

> SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "method"

is this an issue or anything else?? Thanks in advance

In my application.js file

```
//= require sweetalert2
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require sweet-alert-confirm
//= require_tree .
```

In my gem file

```
gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert2', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'sweet-alert-confirm'
```

In my index.html.erb

```
method: delete, data: { confirm: 'are you sure?' }
```

Comment: Put your code here.

Comment: What did you try with "method" param ? Sweet alert2 don't have "method" param

Comment: problem arise while clicking the delete button and I don't know about the "method" params I flashes in vendor.bundle.js file

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require sweetalert2
//= require sweet-alert-confirm
//= require_tree .
```

`sweetalert2` after `jquery` and `jquery_ujs`

Comment: Try to restart the server

Comment: Tried for your happiness but same problem @fool-dev.. thank you so much for your kind answer